# Can MTOM be used on xs:string data types

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, mtom

I've implemented a prototype WCF service using MTOM [Following a tutorial I found](http://mstecharchitect.blogspot.ca/2009/01/wcf-with-mtom-message-encoding.html).

As long as the data type in any object I an receiving/returning in my WCF service is a byte[], which translates to xs:base64Binary in the wsdl, the .net SOAP framework will leverage MTOM and put the contents of that data as raw binary in additional mime parts.  Works awesome!

My issue is that in my actual implementation I am dealing with a schema that I can not change, and it has a data type of string[]:

> public abstract partial class BIN : ANY {
>
> ```
> ...
>
> /// <remarks/>
> [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
> public string[] Text {
>     get {
>         return this.textField;
>     }
>     set {
>         this.textField = value;
>     }
> }
> ```

In my case, the Text property (or the contents of the element, when in xml form) will be large binary data, and I'd like to use the MTOM functionality to put it as raw binary in additional mime parts, instead of base64 encoding it... Is this possible to do?